# Can serial voting detection be bypassed?

Tags: support, down-votes, serial-voting

[image]

I know there should be a script running and probably I'll get my rep back eventually, but I can't help taking this personally. I mean... WTH? This seems like a petty act. Moreover, I'm going for the Legendary badge, and if I get my rep back on a different day, that's not really helpful.

Who, other than scripts, looks into this? Will the person responsible for this be dealt with in any way?

Is there no way to keep serial downvoting at bay?

Sorry for the duplicate, it's just really REALLY frustrating...

#### EDIT: Some new info

This started 3 days ago. The rep was restored (although not for the same day, so there's a minus there) for the first day. However, yesterday and today it continued. Not as many downvotes, but clearly someone's going out of their way to downvote me. Also, the rep lost yesterday wasn't recovered. **Could someone have figured out how to bypass the scripts?**

[image]

As you can see, more recently the votes are some time apart. I only highlighted those that are on old questions. Agreed, you might stumble into an old question and downvote it, but to me this seems like much more than a coincidence.

Comment: FWIW, I don't think you need to worry for Epic/Legendary, stuff gets recalc'd after serial vote removals.

Comment: @Mat still freakin' frustrating...

Comment: Mods will look into it if you raise a flag. But usually the scripts are sufficient to take care of the problem. Wait 24-36 hours before raising a flag just to give the scripts a chance to work. (cc @mKorbel )

Comment: +1 and a re-open vote from me, this looks like someone is being sneaky and trying to avoid the detection scripts here.

Comment: Not only trying... but succeeding...  This might indicate that it is not a new user, rather a user that understands the system... Scary thought...

Comment: Yes... you disagree with an answer or write a comment that someone doesn't like, and POW!

Comment: I agree with @awoodland. There's much overlap among the posts getting downvoted now and those from the last reversed serial downvoting.

Comment: This reminds me of [Consistent serial downvoting now avoiding detection](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130844/consistent-serial-downvoting-now-avoiding-detection) simply because the topic is similar and that one was active yesterday.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

A user was trying to stay "under the radar" with respect to downvoting you (several checks are in place, he was doing it at a *very* low volume as to avoid all of them).  We have invalidated all involved votes.

The offender has been dealt with.  If, after their vacation, they offer an encore...let's just say they don't want to do that...

Comment: Thank you, that's great news. I assume he shall remain anonymous? :)

Comment: @LuchianGrigore - yeah, we tend to handle these things privately for (hopefully) obvious reasons